# Store LINQ result into view-model refereeing to multiple class objects instead of storing LINQ result in var

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, viewmodel

I have linq statement that gives three class object data

1- appForm
2- ebsSync
3- SyncAuditLog

```
var _AppForms2 = (from appForm in _uof.Web_AppFormsRepository.GetAll()
                          join syncAuditLog in (_uof.Web_SyncAuditLogRepository.GetAll().
                                                 Where(sal => sal.LOG_STATUS.Equals("EP") &&
                                                       sal.LOOKUP_ID != null &&
                                                       sal.ID == maxAuditID)
                                                 .Select(shortListedAuditLog => new { shortListedAuditLog })) on appForm.SUBMISSION_ID equals syncAuditLog.shortListedAuditLog.SUBMISSION_ID
                          join ebsSync in _uof.Web_EBS_SyncRepository.GetAll() on appForm.SUBMISSION_ID equals ebsSync.SUBMISSION_ID
                          select new {appForm , ebsSync, syncAuditLog }).ToList();
```

[image]

I want to store this LINQ query result into viewModel as instead of 'var _AppForms';

```
 public class WebSyncSummaryEntity
{
    public List<Web_AppFormsEntity> AppFormsEntity { get; set; }

    public List<Web_EBS_SyncEntity> EBS_SyncEntity { get; set; }

    public List<Web_SyncAuditLogEntity> SyncAuditLogEntity { get; set; }
}
```

### Need to fix here!

```
 public List<WebSyncSummaryEntity> GetWebSyncSummary()
    {
        List<WebSyncSummaryEntity> _AppForms = null;

        using (var _uof = new UCAS_WebSync_AdminTool_UOF())
        {

            var maxAuditID = (from sal in _uof.Web_SyncAuditLogRepository.GetAll().Where(
                                                                                   sal => sal.LOG_STATUS.Equals("EP") &&
                                                                                   sal.LOOKUP_ID != null)
                              select sal).Max(x => x.ID);


   _AppForms = (from appForm in _uof.Web_AppFormsRepository.GetAll()
                          join syncAuditLog in (_uof.Web_SyncAuditLogRepository.GetAll().
                                                 Where(sal => sal.LOG_STATUS.Equals("EP") &&
                                                       sal.LOOKUP_ID != null &&
                                                       sal.ID == maxAuditID)
                                                 .Select(shortListedAuditLog => new { shortListedAuditLog })) on appForm.SUBMISSION_ID equals syncAuditLog.shortListedAuditLog.SUBMISSION_ID
                          join ebsSync in _uof.Web_EBS_SyncRepository.GetAll() on appForm.SUBMISSION_ID equals ebsSync.SUBMISSION_ID
                          select new {appForm , ebsSync, syncAuditLog }).ToList();

            var test = "d";
        }

        return _AppForms;
    }
```

Comment: Your query returns 1 list which contains 3 objects. Instead of returning 1 object containing 3 lists. So, you should group the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your view model

```
public class WebSyncSummaryEntity
{
    public Web_AppFormsEntity AppFormsEntity { get; set; }

    public Web_EBS_SyncEntity EBS_SyncEntity { get; set; }

    public Web_SyncAuditLogEntity SyncAuditLogEntity { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
var _AppForms2 = (from appForm in _uof.Web_AppFormsRepository.GetAll()
                          join syncAuditLog in (_uof.Web_SyncAuditLogRepository.GetAll().
                                                 Where(sal => sal.LOG_STATUS.Equals("EP") &&
                                                       sal.LOOKUP_ID != null &&
                                                       sal.ID == maxAuditID)
                                                 .Select(shortListedAuditLog => new { shortListedAuditLog })) on appForm.SUBMISSION_ID equals syncAuditLog.shortListedAuditLog.SUBMISSION_ID
                          join ebsSync in _uof.Web_EBS_SyncRepository.GetAll() on appForm.SUBMISSION_ID equals ebsSync.SUBMISSION_ID
                          select new WebSyncSummaryEntity {AppFormsEntity =appForm , EBS_SyncEntity =ebsSync, SyncAuditLogEntity =syncAuditLog }).ToList();
```

I haven't tested the code, just suggesting you a way to go, looking for better solution.

Comment: glad to know, happy codding